# Substitute 2 IDs by Name in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables that looks like the below:

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaH3g.jpg)

[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9f92c.jpg)

What Im trying to do, is I want to substitute the change_builder ID from table 1 by the first and last name from table 2. In addition, I want to do the same for the change_manager_ID in table 2 (Substitute it by the first and last name from table 2)

My query looks like the below:

```
SELECT a.change_number, a.title, change_manager_id,change_builder_id, concat(users.first_name,' ', users.last_name) as Manager_Name, concat(users.first_name,' ', users.last_name) as Builder_Name,

(CASE 
WHEN a.change_state_id = '128' THEN 'In Progress'
WHEN a.change_state_id = '127' THEN 'Approved'
WHEN a.change_state_id = '125' THEN 'Pending'
WHEN a.change_state_id = '124' THEN 'Requested'

END) AS Change_State

FROM change_item as a
LEFT JOIN users
ON a.change_manager_id = users.id


WHERE a.change_state_id = 128
OR a.change_state_id = 124
OR a.change_state_id = 125
OR a.change_state_id = 127
```

The output of this is changing the first and last name of the manager w.r.t the ID but I want to do the same for the builder as well.

I'm stuck, any help or hint would be really appreciated.

Comment: Join the table twice; once for managers and once for builders

Comment: Tried that, it doesn't work since it's not a unique table/ alias

Comment: I was hoping you might be able to figure out that part of the problem for yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have forgotten that you can join a table twice to the same other table - each join depicting a different relationship.
Good practice requires you to give each join clause a good correlation name to describe the role of the relationship.

And, please, use the right literals for the right types.

Not once `change_state_id = '128'` (string) and then `change_state_id = 124` (number). Implicit conversions are slow and can impact the data quality.

And I used an IN () clause instead of a bunch of OR-s:

```
SELECT 
   a.change_number
  ,a.title
  ,change_manager_id
  ,change_builder_id
  ,CONCAT (mgr.first_name,' ',mgr.last_name) AS Manager_Name
  ,CONCAT (bld.first_name,' ',bld.last_name) AS Builder_Name
  ,CASE 
     WHEN a.change_state_id = 128 THEN 'In Progress'
     WHEN a.change_state_id = 127 THEN 'Approved'
     WHEN a.change_state_id = 125 THEN 'Pending'
     WHEN a.change_state_id = 124 THEN 'Requested'
   END AS Change_State
FROM change_item AS a
LEFT JOIN users AS mgr -- join as manager
ON a.change_manager_id = mgr.id
LEFT JOIN users AS bld -- join as builder
ON a.change_builder_id = bld.id
WHERE a.change_state_id IN(128,124,125,127)
    ;
```